# How play a .tmp file with MPMoviePlayerController in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I download a video file .mp4 from server with `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` but in the delegate `didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location`, location is a .tmp file like this

`file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/BEA4F9F8-D685-468F-B96C-AE7890ACFC5E/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_LQuGoo.tmp`

When I try to initialize MPMoviePlayerController console show this error

`_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: { kind = 1;new = 2; old = 0;}` and screen show black

I researched and I can save the .tmp file and play .mp4 from my directory but I don't want to do that, I want to know if there is a way to play directly with MPMoviePlayerController. My code

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
NSURLSession *downloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask =[downloadSession downloadTaskWithURL:self.userRecord.URL completionHandler:nil];
[downloadTask resume];


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

    self.userRecord.locationData = location;

    [(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fileDownloaderDidFinish:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;

}


-(void)fileDownloaderDidFinish:(FileDownloader *)fileDownloader {


        [self setVideoPlayer:[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileDownloader.userRecord.locationData]]
        ;
        [self.videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.vwContainerVideo addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.btPlay];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.imPlay];
        [self.vwContainerThumbnail setHidden:YES];
        [AnimationHelper fadeIn:self.vwContainerVideo withDuration:0.5 andWait:0.5];
        [self.vwContainerVideo setHidden:NO];
        [self.videoPlayer play];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My decision was to save file .tmp in a directory and init `MPMoviePlayerController` with the url from directory.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
NSURLSession *downloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask =[downloadSession downloadTaskWithURL:self.userRecord.URL completionHandler:nil];
[downloadTask resume];


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
     self.userRecord.data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
     [self.userRecord.data writeToFile:[rootDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@",self.userRecord.directory,self.userRecord.nameFile, self.userRecord.ext]] options:NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting error:&error];
     self.userRecord.locationData = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[rootDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@",self.userRecord.directory,self.userRecord.nameFile, self.userRecord.ext]]];

    [(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fileDownloaderDidFinish:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;

}


-(void)fileDownloaderDidFinish:(FileDownloader *)fileDownloader {


        [self setVideoPlayer:[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileDownloader.userRecord.locationData]]
        ;
        [self.videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.vwContainerVideo addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.videoPlayer.view];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.btPlay];
        [self.vwContainerVideo bringSubviewToFront:self.imPlay];
        [self.vwContainerThumbnail setHidden:YES];
        [AnimationHelper fadeIn:self.vwContainerVideo withDuration:0.5 andWait:0.5];
        [self.vwContainerVideo setHidden:NO];
        [self.videoPlayer play];

}
```